# JavaScript: AreaText split per line error

Tags: javascript, split, textarea

What is the problem with this code?

```
var lines = document.getElementById('id="summoners"').val().split('\n');

//I get error above "Cannot call method val of null

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++)
{
   //other code using lines[i] not necessary to show it
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('summoners')` is the syntax you'd want to access the element and is why you're getting the null reference exception.

`.val()` is a jQuery-like method, though, and will fail on a raw HTML element. You'd need to use something like `document.getElementById('summoners').value`, assuming it's a `textarea` element, or use jQuery and do `$('#summoners').val()`.

Comment: lshearer is correct to point out that .val() is a jQuery method (perhaps available in any number of other frameworks as well). Your error is due to the fact that you're calling a method (any method, really) on a null object, but even if your getElementById was returning your element properly, the .val() method probably wouldn't work in this instance.

Comment: Dont know if i can keep asking, but im having another problem.
It seems my areatext is NOT EMPTY, and i dont have nothing on it.

if(document.getElementById('summoners').value == null) isnt working...
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your getElementById is malformed. You need not specify the "id" key in the method argument. Go with:

```
document.getElementById('summoners').val().split('\n');
```

Comment: I guess i need a break! :)
Thank you but now it says 

"object #<HTMLTextAreaElement> has no method val". :O